# Permission denied when install featherdubster at python

Tags: permissions, lubuntu, python3

I'm trying to install a python package call `featherduster`. I followed the guide here https://github.com/nccgroup/featherduster/blob/master/INSTALL.md
But when i execute
`heeyoung@Tindertron:~/featherduster$ python3 setup.py install`

i got the following error:

```
error: can't create or remove files in install directory
```

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/test-easy-install-41100.write-test'
```

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/
```

I've looked for solutions on `stackoverflow` and `askubuntu` but it did't work.
I tried
`python3 setup.py install --user` or `python3 setup.py install --prefix=[location]`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use sudo privileges, you can install this package inside a [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html#linux-installers) environment.

Once conda is installed (no need sudo, and you can install python>=3, even if you want to use python 2):

```
conda create -n myenv 'python<3'
conda activate myenv # you will need to do this each time you want to use your package
cd ~/featherduster
python setup.py install
```

`conda` is a package manager for user space, like `apt` is for the system administrator. I recommend to use `conda` when it's for user needs, because you will never break system side python.

Answer (score -1):

It is permission issue. To fix it you have run installation script with root privileges.

Open terminal and type:

```
cd ~/featherduster
sudo python2 setup.py install
```